# Google maps 'filtered' api

Tags: android

I'm really stuck on finding out whether there's an api key that will just 'filter' the views on my map so that it just shows specific ones, like say hospitals. I'd really appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to import GOOGLE PLACES API and in which you have to select google places types  like below these many options are there.
just select the types and get the values:
**
Api link below
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/supported_types

-accounting
airport
amusement_park
aquarium
art_gallery
atm
bakery
bank
bar
beauty_salon
bicycle_store
book_store
bowling_alley
bus_station
cafe
campground
car_dealer
car_rental
car_repair
car_wash
casino
cemetery
church
city_hall
clothing_store
convenience_store
courthouse
dentist
department_store
doctor
electrician
electronics_store
embassy
establishment (deprecated)
finance (deprecated)
fire_station
florist
food (deprecated)
funeral_home
furniture_store
gas_station
general_contractor (deprecated)
grocery_or_supermarket (deprecated)
gym
hair_care
hardware_store
health (deprecated)
hindu_temple
home_goods_store
hospital
insurance_agency
jewelry_store
laundry
lawyer
library
liquor_store
local_government_office
locksmith
lodging
meal_delivery
meal_takeaway
mosque
movie_rental
movie_theater
moving_company
museum
night_club
painter
park
parking
pet_store
pharmacy
physiotherapist
place_of_worship (deprecated)
plumber
police
post_office
real_estate_agency
restaurant
roofing_contractor
rv_park
school
shoe_store
shopping_mall
spa
stadium
storage
store
subway_station
synagogue
taxi_stand
train_station
transit_station
travel_agency
university
veterinary_care
zoo

**